# Detect tapping the android back button to close the keyboard in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, keyboard-events

I am searching for a possibility to detect when the user taps the android back button on the bottom in order to close the keyboard in flutter.
The problem is the following: If the user taps a text field, it gets the focus and the keyboard appears, everything is fine here. I put the text field inside a GestureDetector so if the user taps somewhere outside the text field, unfocus() is called. But on android there is another way to close the keyboard: Using the back button from the smartphone on the bottom.
Is there any way to detect when the user taps it while the keyboard was open? As I understand, WillPopScope only works when the back button points to the left, but when the keyboard is opened, the back button points to the bottom and it has another purpose.
The keyboard_visibility package did not work for me. When adding a listener to the KeyboardVisibilityNotification, the methods onHide and onChanged did not fire.

Comment: This is two questions, you'll find the answer If you split the question in two parts...

Comment: I'm searching for a way to detect closing the keyboard by tapping the android back button in flutter and I added that the KeyboardVisibility package did not work. Not sure what the second question is but I hope it is clear now.

Comment: @KönigWey Hi, I am trying to achieve the same thing. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Hi, yes I use the keyboard_visibility package, just initialize the controller

final KeyboardVisibilityController _keyboardController = KeyboardVisibilityController();

and add the listener method onChange in initState():

_keyboardController.onChange.listen((bool isVisible) {
    if (!isVisible && mounted) {
        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    }
});

Comment: The answer from Joel worked for me, you should accept it for future reference!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the keyboard_visibility package is no longer updated, you can use this new one: [Flutter Keyboard Visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility). It uses null safety and is getting updates.

Here is my approach, using the FocusManager instead of the FocusScope.

```dart
late final KeyboardVisibilityController _keyboardVisibilityController;
late StreamSubscription<bool> keyboardSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _keyboardVisibilityController = KeyboardVisibilityController();
    keyboardSubscription = _keyboardVisibilityController.onChange.listen((isVisible) {
      if (!isVisible) FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    keyboardSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

See the [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility#option-3-direct-query-and-subscription) for alternative implementations.

Comment: This can lead to an error, esp. if you have to call setState onChange as your example does not show how to properly cancel the StreamSubscription and dispose it. I suggested an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Use the keyboard_visibility package: https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_visibility.

The onHide callback does not fire for some reason, so you have to use onChange instead and check if the visibility is false.

Answer (score -2):

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return WillPopScope(
         child: Scaffold(.....),
          onWillPop: () async {
            var currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
            if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus && currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
              currentFocus.focusedChild.unfocus();
              return false;
            }else{
              return true;
            }
          },
        );
    }
```

Use WillPopScope to close the keyboard on backpress event

Comment: onWillPop is only called if you try to pop the route, which is not the case here. Tapping the android button (arrow down) to close the keyboard has nothing to do with routes, it just closes the keyboard